# Exists $t^*\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y(t^*)=-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'=y^2-3y+2, y(0) = \frac{3}{2}$

Exists $t^*\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y(t^*)=-1$?.

How to prove without solving the ode? Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation admits two constant solutions, $y=1$ and $y=2$. By uniqueness, any other solution cannot intersect these constant solutions. Since $y(0) \in (1, 2)$, then you must have $1 < y(t) < 2$ for every $t$.

Comment: I guess you should invoke Picard–Lindelöf directly at this level.

Comment: Yes, sure: the r.h.s. is a smooth function (hence locally Lipschitz), so that we have uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $y^2-3y+2=(y-2)(y-1)<0$ iff $y\in (1,2)$. Use this to show that for $t>0$ you have $y(t)\in [1,\frac{3}{2}]$ and for $t\leq 0$ you have $y(t)\in [\frac{3}{2},\infty)$.